# what does def * (def asterisk) mean?

Tags: scala

an example in some code I'm looking at

```
class X {
    def k1 = column[Int]("k1")
    def k2 = column[Int]("k2")
    def * = (k1, k2)
}
```

Is it just a normal function name or is there something special about it?

Comment: Yes is a normal function name. However, it seems weird as a no args function, usually one would use that name for something resembling a multiplication. For example `2 * 4` - remember that **Scala** does not have operators, the previous code is calling the `*` method on the **Int** class.

Comment: Is this code simplified from a class extending `Slick`'s `Table`?

Comment: @Feyyaz yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the name of an abstract method in [Slick](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.3.0/introduction.html)'s `Table`, used to tell Slick how it should convert those columns into a Scala object, and the Scala object back into the database columns. The complete code in your question would be

```
class X(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, Int)] {
    def k1 = column[Int]("k1")
    def k2 = column[Int]("k2")
    override def * : ProvenShape[(Int, Int)] = (k1, k2) // you may prefer to omit 'override' and return type for readability
}
```

So, if you extend `Table`, you have to override this method.

You can find more complex usages in the [documentation](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.3.0/introduction.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is just a normal function name. Scala allows pretty much any sequence of characters to be a function name, though some need to be quoted using backticks.

```
def `def` = "def"
```